# How can I use openssl rand to generate more than 2GiB of data?

Tags: random, openssl

Can I use the "openssl rand" command to generate more than 2GiB of data?

```
openssl rand 2147483647 | pv > /dev/null 
2.00GiB 0:00:01 [1.45GiB/s] [        <=> 
openssl rand 2147483648
rand: Value "2147483648" outside integer range
rand: Use -help for summary.
```

The limit of 2GiB seems to be arbitrary.

Thank you!

PS: I'm using this command

```
openssl enc -e -chacha20 -k $(pwgen -ync 40 1) -pbkdf2 -in /dev/zero | openssl enc -e -aes-256-ctr -k $(pwgen -ync 40 1) -pbkdf2 | pv > /dev/null
```

to generate an endless stream of random data. It's useful for example to prepare the hard-drive for the encryption.

Comment: The byte count argument is stored in signed C `int` which is evidently 32 bits on that platform. You could just put it in a loop.

Comment: 2^31=2147483648, 2^31-1=2147483647 should work. You could generate multiple streams and append one after another

Comment: This is clearly limitation of `openssl rand`. Possible WA: `while true; do openssl rand 2147483647; done | pv > /dev/null`. I have opened a RFE for openssl https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/22622 and we are discussing to add support for suffixes byl k, M, G, T, P ...